# PhantomJS: injecting a script before any other scripts run

Tags: phantomjs

Using PhantomJS, I'd like to inject some JS as if there was an extra `<script>` tag before any other `<script>` tags. This is because the scripts on the page use some functions that PhantomJS does not have, namely `Function.prototype.bind` and `window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame`. I have a JS file with custom implementations of the two and I'd like PhantomJS to use them when running the scripts on the page.

The difficulty is that if I do page.injectJs before page.open, the script is injected into an empty page and is not carried over to the page being opened.

Alternatively, if I do page.injectJs after page.open, it's too late as the JavaScript errors (undefined functions) have already occurred.

I've found a way that appears to work, but is obviously a hack:

```
page.onResourceReceived = function() {
    page.injectJs('phantom-hacks.js')
};
```

This injects it many times (twice for each resource, apparently), but that's okay because my script is idempotent. However, I'd like to know the proper way to do this: inject it only once and before any scripts on the page are run.

Thanks :)

Comment: why not keep a hash with all the files you want to inject where the key is the file and the value is whether it was injected or not and it if hasn't been injected then inject it? Or you could just stop the event listener after the first run?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I don't think there's a "proper" way to inject such script other than hooking to events.
I've spent half a year working massively with PhantomJs and found no way to inject before all the errors start happening but after the page finished loading.

I would try to go through onInitialized, onLoadStarted, onLoadFinished. Inside the hooks I would call to page.evaluate() which would just modify DOM to have this extra  whatever place you like.

I think one of them (the hooks) should give you the right timing you want.

Cheers

Comment: Using `onInitialized` and `injectJs` (passing the relative path to the polyfills) worked perfectly in my case.

Comment: @MarcoLazzeri thanks for your comment, `onInitialized` is exactly what I needed for the same purpose.