# phantomJS includeJs method always fails to load script via Operation Cancelled

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm trying to load some scripts into my pages being visited by phantomjs.  I'm using 2.1.1 btw.

I'm kind of banging my head here because I've tried a variety of things and they all seem to fail in the same way which kind of makes me think maybe I'm missing a configuration setting or something.

Any who what I'm trying :

```
//I dont actually care about using jquery, just trying loading from different servers
page.includeJs('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js');
```

and

```
page.includeJs('https://aSiteIControl.com/jquery.min.js');
```

and then I have a onResourceError handler like this:

```
page.onResourceError = function(resourceError) {
    console.error(resourceError.url + ': ' + resourceError.errorString);
    console.error(JSON.stringify(resourceError))
};
```

that outputs this no matter what I've tried:

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js: Operation canceled
{"errorCode":5,"errorString":"Operation canceled","id":1,"status":null,"statusText":null,"url":"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"}
```

This seems to happen no matter what protocol I use or what server the script lives on.  Also, both of those examples are visitable in a browser.  Any body have any idea what I might be doing wrong?

**TO BE CLEAR on the accepted answer since there is no code:**

just go look at this question :

[PhantomJS: injecting a script before any other scripts run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15459049/phantomjs-injecting-a-script-before-any-other-scripts-run)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PhantomJS: injecting a script before any other scripts run](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15459049/phantomjs-injecting-a-script-before-any-other-scripts-run)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be caused by a timeout or the call to the exit() function of the phantom object while the js is being loaded, or if you try to open another page. Can you add all your code?

Based on the [documentation](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/include-js.html) you can include external JS:

> Includes external script from the specified url (usually a remote location)

Comment: Hmm.  Im at lunch so i cant immediately try it, , but i wonder if page.open can be in the callback.  Id been assuming includeJs was something set before running page.open

Comment: yup, my suspicion was correct.  Thanks for the gleen :)

Answer (score 3):

I bet you can include directly only local scripts. Please try:

```
    (page.evaluate(function() {
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = 'http://urlToScript.com';
    }))
```

Comment: That would work, but i need the included script to load before other things on the page.  My intended use case is actually to polyfill some es6 stuff that is breaking certain pages since phantom doesnt fully support es6 yet.

Comment: What with: download web page, modify it (with adding js) and execute it inside page module ?